# "MySQL server has gone away" when connecting to server with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

So, I have a weird issue on my Ubuntu (18.04) server:

I have PHP (7.2.10) and MySQL (8.0.12) running. When I try to connect to the MySQL database from a PHP page, I get the error "MySQL server has gone away". In *every* search I've done, all the fixes are for when that error appears when sending a query. (I'm not even getting to that point, yet.)

The mysql.err and mysql.log files are either blank or have unrelated warnings (no errors). I've increased my timeout and max_allowed_packet to no avail. Also, I can connect to the database remotely with other programs, so I know the server is responding to requests.

I set MySQL to allow connections from [User]@% (I know, that's a bad idea; I'll change it back once I get beyond this problem.)

I'm using the same user I can use to access the database remotely.

Any ideas?

Relevant part of the script (Though, at this point, I'm >90% certain the problem isn't with the script itself)

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $user, $password, $DB, $port);

if ($conn->connect_error)//Test connection
{ //On fail, send an alert and populate manually
  echo "<script>alert('Connection failed: $conn->connect_error! $conn->host_info');</script>\n";/*populate manually*/
}
else //run query; it never gets here.
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can read this page first.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gone-away.html

There are two most posibility :

1. By default, the server closes the connection after eight hours if nothing has happened. You can change the time limit by setting the wait_timeout variable when you start mysqld. See Section 5.1.7, “Server System Variables”.
2. If you have a script, you just have to issue the query again for the client to do an automatic reconnection. This assumes that you have automatic reconnection in the client enabled (which is the default for the mysql command-line client).

Hope that can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But, as I mentioned in my original question, I already increased the timeout variable. Also, this is happening on the *initial* connection to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and it seems to be working with WAMP (Maybe a configuration issue on your side).

However, there is another case where the connection can be lost. It happens with prepared statements. If you loose or replace the connection reference ($conn in your case) and execute the statement after, you'll end up with the "MySQL has gone away error".

Example snippet bellow:

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $user, $password, $DB, $port);

if ($conn->connect_error)
{
    echo "<script>alert('Connection failed: $conn->connect_error! $conn->host_info');</script>\n";/*populate manually*/
}
else {
    //Reference lost when replacing the connection instance with the statement
    $conn = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM $someTable");
    $conn->execute();

    echo $conn->error;
}
?>
```

In this case the error wouldn't occur during connection but instead during query execution.

Otherwise it's most likely a configuration error in which case you could try reinstalling MySQL default configuration.